# Ubuntu 11.04 hangs when try to resume from screen lock.

Tags: lock-screen

Sometimes if I lock my Ubuntu 11.04 screen, when I try to resume my work.. I see my PC hangs. The black screen does not go off. I can not even see the password prompt screen. I have to restart the PC. The same thing happens with my PC and my friends's PC.

**My Sytem**

- Ubuntu 11.04 (natty)
- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7400  @ 2.80GHz (GenuineIntel)
- 3982 MiB (Memory)

Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: Heppened to me once as well.

Comment: Again I encountered this problem. Now a new restart. Damn! I lost my all opened programs.

Comment: That's it, report a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Disable lock screen temporary,

review this link...

[Disable the Screensaver Lock in Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/disable-screensaver-lock-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/)

Comment: this looks like working for me. let me check and reply you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think you are probably experiencing this bug:
[Natty Screensaver freezes system after some period of inactivity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/762918)

It is reported in the bug thread that it can be worked around by disabling "Sync to VBlank" in the OpenGL plug-in of CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm), but this may not work for everyone.

The bug is marked as a "High" so hopefully it will be fixed soon.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 Natty on a Dell laptop.  I was unable to suspend and resume, the resume would wake the computer, but the computer did not respond.  My solution was to remove the following packages:

```
acpi-support
acpid
```

Now suspend and resume work everytime, including just closing the lid and re-opening. :)  Hope it helps.